# '3704' Operation is not allowed when the object is closed

Tags: sql-server, excel, vba

```
Dim ConnDB As ADODB.Connection
Dim RecSet As ADODB.Recordset
Dim ConnStr As String
Dim SQL_Query As String
Dim iCols As Integer
Const ClaimSheet = "Sheet1"


Set ConnDB = New ADODB.Connection
Set RecSet = New ADODB.Recordset

Const SQLServer = "*****"
Const SQLDB = "*****"

ConnStr = "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Data Source=" & SQLServer & ";" & _
                  "Initial Catalog=" & SQLDB & ";" & _
                  "Integrated Security=SSPI;"
                  
ConnDB.ConnectionTimeout = 3
ConnDB.Open ConnStr
ConnDB.CommandTimeout = 30

SQL_Query = "EXEC [dbo].[Pivot_Claims]"

Set RecSet = ConnDB.Execute(SQL_Query)

If Not RecSet.EOF Then
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ClaimSheet).Range("B6").CopyFromRecordset RecSet
    RecSet.Close    
Else
    MsgBox "No Records Found"
End If
```

I'm trying to run the above VBA code to execute a stored procedure (Pivot_Claims) and paste the results into ClaimSheet. I am getting the error 'Operation is not allowed when the object is closed.' which pointes to the ' If Not RecSet.EOF Then' line.

Comment: Have you turned the count off the stored proc? `SET NOCOUNT ON`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to turn the count off on the stored proc.

`SET NOCOUNT ON`